# npm httpsnippet library throwing error in reactjs tsx component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, package

I'm trying to make code snippets of different languages. I have installed httpsnippet npm package latest version 3.0.1. But when I try to use that the HTTPSnippet class shows me that it accepts argument type HarEntry | HarRequest. But I followed the documentation and just copy the code from there.

I'm using that inside a Reactjs project and in a .tsx extension file.

```
const generateSnippet = () => {
    const snippet = new HTTPSnippet({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mockbin.com/request',
    });

    const options = { indent: '\t' };
    const output = snippet.convert('shell', 'curl', options);
    console.log(output);
}
```

I tried searching on the google but nothing found.

The error is the following:

ERROR in src/components/WorkSpace/RightSideBar/TabsContent/SnippetsTab.tsx:21:35
TS2345: Argument of type '{ method: string; url: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HarEntry | HarRequest'.
Type '{ method: string; url: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HarRequest'.
Type '{ method: string; url: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Request, "postData">': headers, httpVersion, cookies, queryString, and 2 more.